# Exhaust fan in Toilet room off the master bath

Tags: code-compliance, exhaust-fan, exhaust-vent

I understand it is code for exhaust fan in the Toilet room (Small 4x5 room with door) this room is off the main master bathroom. Do I need another exhaust for the main bathroom for code?  Can I put a T on the exhaust 4" duct and add a second fan above shower?

Lastly, best way to just turn on the toilet room fan automatically when the can light above the shower is used? One light switch for the light over the shower and the fan has a separate fan and builtin light switch in the toilet room.

Looking for suggestions on how to proceed? Separate exhaust or continue to automate fan to turn on when shower is used? House has been like this for 20 years and just now getting mold on the ceiling of shower. I could use existing Smartthings Hub Automation and add smart switches to work out details but would rather hard wire to automate exahust.

Comment: Is there a window in either room? I believe if a window of 1.5 square feet total area is available no fan is required but I think they are always a good idea.

Comment: @EdBeal while a window may meet code's vent requirements, in many parts of the country opening a window during or shortly after a shower isn't a realistic possibility for significant stretches of the year. A vent fan is a nicer option, all things considered.

Comment: @freeman I fully understand that finish reading my comment , they are always a good idea.

Comment: Can you provide a citation to back up your understanding that exhaust fans are needed in *both* the toilet room *and* the overall bathroom it's attached to?  I'm not finding any specific language that points me at that understanding....

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel _Do I need another exhaust for the main bathroom for code?_ OP doesn't know - he's asking. Then asking a second question about how to do it.

Comment: No Window to open. @edbeal.

Comment: @threephaseEel, I only read on other forums that a fan is needed in NC in the toilet room. I have not confirmed this. If not, I will move the exhaust fan to the main bathroom.